# Configure block in Jenkins pipelinejob using DSL?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

Trying to write a DSL Jenkins pipeline job using jobs-dsl and not sure if I'm hitting a couple of pipeline job limitations or am missing something more fundamental.

1 - Configuring "Polling ignores commits in certain paths" under "Additional Behaviours" using the configure block does not seem to be working as expected in the pipeline job; I have tested and this configure block works as expected in a freestyle job dsl. Searched and couldn't find anything relevant - can someone confirm if the below is supported/not supported within the below pipeline job?

```
    pipelineJob("ProjA/pipeline") 
    {
        logRotator
        {
          daysToKeep 10
          numToKeep 30
        }
        definition 
        {
          cpsScm 
          {
            scm
            {
                git('git@github.com:sample-org/pipeline.git', '*/develop')
            }
            configure { gitScm -> 
                gitScm / 'extensions' << 'hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.PathRestriction' {
                    excludedRegions('sample/dirs')
                }
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

2 - How do we pass credentials to the git under scm block under pipeline? Works for freestyle jobs but having trouble getting it to work here

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in DSL only supports basic options. But the [Dynamic DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL) supports almost any option.

```
pipelineJob('example') {
  definition {
    cpsScmFlowDefinition {
      scm {
        gitSCM {
          userRemoteConfigs {
            userRemoteConfig {
              url('git@github.com:sample-org/pipeline.git')
              name('master')
              refspec(null)
              credentialsId('example')
            }
          }
          branches {
            branchSpec {
              name('*/develop')
            }
          }
          extensions {
            pathRestriction {
              includedRegions(null)
              excludedRegions('sample/dirs')
            } 
          }
          doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations(false)
          browser {}
          gitTool(null)
        }
      }
      scriptPath('Jenkinsfile')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI for normal pipeline

Git checkout using credentials referring to the [git plugin step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/#-git-%20git) :

```
    stage('checkout') {
        git credentialsId: '<credentialsID from credentials plugin>',
        url: 'git@repository.foo/repoName.git',
        branch: 'master' 
    }
```

Reg. [scm plugin step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Surround-SCM-plugin/#-sscm-%20surround%20scm)

```
 stage('checkout') {
     checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM',
        userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://repository.foo/git/fooRepoName.git' ,
            credentialsId: 'credentialsIDToUseFromCredentialsPlugin']],
            branches: [[name:'refs/tags/TAGNAME']]],
        poll:false      
 }

stage('checkout') {
     checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM',
        userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://repository.foo/git/fooRepoName.git' ,
            credentialsId: 'credentialsIDToUseFromCredentialsPlugin']],
            branches: [[name:'BRANCHNAME']]],
        poll:false      
 }
```

And I was never looking for poll if it works or not

Comment: But this is for usage in a Jenkinsfile within [tag:jenkins-pipeline], not for [tag:jenkins-job-dsl].

Comment: Which is not necessarily wrong.. just it could be clarified that this can not just be inserted into the snipped posted by the author.

Comment: Nope, Job DSL, a separate plugin (see [plugin site](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl))

Comment: Thanks @xxxvodnikxxx - but as StephenKing mentions looking for a jobs-dsl equivalent to use within the pipelinejob